# VS2019 explicit specialization requires template<> error with 'using' keyword

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2019, using

I have this piece of c++ code, and *VS2019* to compile it:

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename t>
class c
{

};

int main(){
    using o = class c<int>;
}
```

does anybody know why it does not compile, complaining about:

```
Error   C2906   'c<int>': explicit specialization requires 'template <>'
```

With *mingw-gcc* it compiles and runs without error.

Here you can compare compiler outputs: https://godbolt.org/z/55fMzh8qz

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Microsoft is on a strict diet. Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2906?view=msvc-170) help?

Comment: There is no `second<int>` in the code. `class` is absolutely unneeded there.

Comment: Thanks @S.M. it actually compiles without the ```class``` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` is unnecessary in the using statement, I think visual studio thinks you are trying to declare a specialisation of `c`:

```
template <>
class c<int>;
```

hence the error message.

All you need is:

```
using o = c<int>;
```